# How to add multiple text above each object in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am facing a problem for more then 2 weeks, i can't find any solution for adding in an efficient way (without down trop in the performance of animation) multiple labels to my scene and each label will be positioned above each object and describe something about it. so far, i followed various examples and code along with them but in the end those examples didn't work for me. So, I am going to join with this question a picture of my scene and the code where I attempt to add text but didn't work.

[Here is the repo of my code without three library](https://github.com/OukhellouFst/objects_with_labels_threejs.git)

[and the picture of my scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4RjL.png)

Comment: I'll do it right now

Comment: You must add the code to the question, a link to an off-site resource is not enough. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)